# Keeping socket open to send files on timer calls?

Tags: java, sockets, timer

I'm writing a program that requires an image to be fetched from a remote server every 10 milliseconds or so, as that's how often the image is updated. My current method calls a timer to grab the image, but it encounters `Socket Closed` errors all the time, and sometimes does not work at all.

How can I fix my methods to keep the socket open the whole time, so no reconnecting is needed?

Here is the full class:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Connection {
    public static void createServer() throws IOException {
        Capture.getScreen();
        ServerSocket socket = null;
        try {
            socket = new ServerSocket(12345, 0,
                    InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"));
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Server started on "
                + socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + ":"
                + socket.getLocalPort() + ",\nWaiting for client to connect.");
        final Socket clientConnection = socket.accept();
        System.out.println("Client accepted from "
                + clientConnection.getInetAddress().getHostAddress()
                + ", sending file");
        ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                System.out.println("Sending File");
                try {
                    pipeStreams(new FileInputStream(new File(
                            "captures/sCap.png")),
                            clientConnection.getOutputStream(), 1024);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        System.out.println("closing out connection");
        try {
            clientConnection.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Timer timer = new Timer(10, taskPerformer);
        timer.setRepeats(true);
        timer.start();
    }

    public static void createClient() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Connecting to server.");
        final Socket socket = new Socket();
        try {
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress
                    .getByName("127.0.0.1"), 12345));
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
        ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                System.out.println("Success, retreiving file.");
                try {
                    pipeStreams(socket.getInputStream(), new FileOutputStream(
                            new File("captures/rCap.png")), 1024);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {

                }
            }
        };

        System.out.println("Closing connection");
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Timer timer = new Timer(10, taskPerformer);
        timer.setRepeats(true);
        timer.start();
    }

    public static void pipeStreams(java.io.InputStream source,
            java.io.OutputStream destination, int bufferSize)
            throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        int read = 0;
        while ((read = source.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            destination.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        destination.flush();
        destination.close();
        source.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: _" it encounters Socket Closed errors all the time, and sometimes does not work at all"_ -- this is not sufficient.  Please show a stack trace (and tell us what statement threw the exception) for the failures, and explain _"sometimes does not work at all"_.

Comment: It tracks back to: `socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress
                    .getByName("127.0.0.1"), 12345));`

Comment: **Don't** close the `ServerSocket` till server is not stopped. This line is in problem `socket.close();`

Answer (score 0):

In your method `pipeStreams` you are closing your outputStream, after the input is finished. If you want to output another stream after that stream then don't close it till after you've finished outputting everything. Simply remove the line;

```
destination.close();
```

It appears your using the same method for sending and receiving though, so you will need to close destination independently when receiving and outputting. You should be aware that you will need to define a protocol though, if you want to simply pipe 2 streams consecutively to the same client, the receiver won't know what its expecting and will treat them as a single stream. An easy way to do this would be to first send an integer specifying the number of bytes to be sent. And then your receiver can read that many bytes, before expecting a new length.

Comment: I've removed that line, but it infinitely repeated "Sending File" now, it is never retrieved.

Comment: As I explain in the post, without closing the connection or telling the client how much data to read, it will just keep trying to accept data.